# OCR Scanning Does Not Display Scanned Output

Tags: java, android, ocr

I am currently developing my first app that able to switch activity tab (Android's Fragment). I have 4 tabs, in one of the tabs, I have implemented an image recognition for character recognition (OCR). I used simplified OCR Tesseract library which is called [Easy OCR Library](https://github.com/priyankvex/Easy-Ocr-Scanner-Android) made by [Priyank Verma](https://priyankvex.wordpress.com/2015/09/02/making-an-ocr-app-for-android-using-tesseract/). I have tested the example from that library and it works. But when I use the library for my own app, it doesn't work properly.

Let me explain, in one of my app's tab, I have a 'Scan' button that utilizes use my phone camera to take a picture. After the picture have been taken, my app should scan the captured image in the saved directory for character recognition. Next, my app will return to the previous 'Scan' tab and then will display the output of the character recognition above the 'Scan' button in that tab. And that just it, my app doesn't seem to scan. The real problem is that after the picture have been taken & saved, my app returns back to the tab with no output at all. My code should work but sadly it doesn't. No error, no nothing and I am losing my mind for days to figure out what is wrong.

Here's the code:-

**---------- My App's Manifest ----------**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.kaydarinapp.queueappv2">
    <!-- Save file permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <!-- Read file permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Camera permission -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Internet permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**---------- From My App's Tab ----------**

**My Tab's XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Tab2"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="8pt"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Scan"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My Tab Java**

```
package com.kaydarinapp.queueappv2;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.Config;
import com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.EasyOcrScanner;
import com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo.EasyOcrScannerListener;

/**
 * Created by Kaydarin on 6/1/2016.
 */

//Our class extending fragment
public class Tab2 extends Fragment implements EasyOcrScannerListener {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private FragmentActivity fragActivity;
    EasyOcrScanner mEasyOcrScanner;
    TextView textView;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    Button btnCapture;

    //Overriden method onCreateView
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragActivity = super.getActivity();
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, container, false);

        textView = (TextView) fragActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        // initialize EasyOcrScanner instance.
        mEasyOcrScanner = new EasyOcrScanner(getActivity(), "EasyOcrScanner",
                Config.REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE, "eng");

        // Set ocrScannerListener
        mEasyOcrScanner.setOcrScannerListener(this);

        btnCapture = (Button) linearLayout.findViewById(R.id.button);
        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mEasyOcrScanner.takePicture();
            }
        });

        return linearLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Call onImageTaken() in onActivityResult.
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && requestCode == Config.REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE){
            mEasyOcrScanner.onImageTaken();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback when after taking picture, scanning process starts.
     * Good place to show a progress dialog.
     * @param filePath file path of the image file being processed.
     */
    @Override
    public void onOcrScanStarted(String filePath) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Scanning...");
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Callback when scanning is finished.
     * Good place to hide teh progress dialog.
     * @param bitmap Bitmap of image that was scanned.
     * @param recognizedText Scanned text.
     */
    @Override
    public void onOcrScanFinished(Bitmap bitmap, String recognizedText) {
        textView.setText(recognizedText);
        if (mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

**---------- From Easy OCR Library ----------**

**Easy OCR Library's Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscanner">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

</manifest>
```

**Config Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 */
public class Config {

    public static String TAG = "OcrScanner";
    public static int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1995;

}
```

**EasyOCRScannerListener Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 *
 * Interface for the callbacks for {@link EasyOcrScanner}.
 */
public interface EasyOcrScannerListener {

    public void onOcrScanStarted(String filePath);

    public void onOcrScanFinished(Bitmap bitmap, String recognizedText);
}
```

**EasyOCRScanner Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 *
 * Class to handle scanning of image.
 */
public class EasyOcrScanner {

    protected Activity mActivity;
    private String directoryPathOriginal;
    private String filePathOriginal;
    private int requestCode;
    private EasyOcrScannerListener mOcrScannerListener;
    private String trainedDataCode;

    public EasyOcrScanner(Activity activity, String directoryPath, int requestCode, String trainedDataCode){
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.directoryPathOriginal = directoryPath;
        this.requestCode = requestCode;
        this.trainedDataCode = trainedDataCode;
    }

    public void takePicture(){
        Intent e = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
        this.filePathOriginal = FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPathOriginal) + File.separator + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis() + ".jpg";
        e.putExtra("output", Uri.fromFile(new File(this.filePathOriginal)));

        startActivity(e);
    }

    public void onImageTaken(){
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "onImageTaken with path " + this.filePathOriginal);
        ImageProcessingThread thread = new ImageProcessingThread(this.mOcrScannerListener,
                this.filePathOriginal, this.directoryPathOriginal, this.mActivity, this.trainedDataCode);
        thread.execute();
    }

    private void startActivity(Intent intent){
        if(this.mActivity != null) {
            this.mActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, this.requestCode);
        }
    }

    public void setOcrScannerListener(EasyOcrScannerListener mOcrScannerListener) {
        this.mOcrScannerListener = mOcrScannerListener;
    }


}
```

**FileUtils Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 */
public class FileUtils {

    public static String getDirectory(String folderName) {
        File directory = null;
        directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + folderName);
        if(!directory.exists()) {
            directory.mkdirs();
        }

        return directory.getAbsolutePath();
    }

    public static String getTessdataDirectory(String directoryPath){
        File tessdataDirectory = new File(directoryPath + "/tessdata");
        if (tessdataDirectory.mkdirs()){
            Log.d(Config.TAG, "tessdata directory created");
        }
        return tessdataDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

**ImageProcessingThread Java**

```
package com.wordpress.priyankvex.easyocrscannerdemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

/**
 * Created by Priyank(@priyankvex) on 27/8/15.
 *
 * Async Task to process the image and scan the image using tesseract library.
 * Equipped with proper callbacks.
 */
public class ImageProcessingThread extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private EasyOcrScannerListener mOcrScannerListener;
    private String filePath;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private String scannedText;
    // trained data file used by Tesseract will be copied in directoryPath/tessdata
    private String directoryPath;
    private String absoluteDirectoryPath;
    private Activity mActivity;
    String trainedDataCode;

    public ImageProcessingThread(EasyOcrScannerListener ocrScannerListener, String filePath,
                                 String directoryPath, Activity activity, String trainedDataCode) {
        this.mOcrScannerListener = ocrScannerListener;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.directoryPath = directoryPath;
        this.absoluteDirectoryPath = FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPath);
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.trainedDataCode = trainedDataCode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mOcrScannerListener.onOcrScanStarted(this.filePath);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        processImage();
        makeTessdataReady();
        scannedText = scanImage();
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "Scanned test : " + scannedText);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        mOcrScannerListener.onOcrScanFinished(mBitmap, scannedText);
    }

    private void processImage() {
        int imageOrientationCode = getImageOrientation();
        Bitmap rawBitmap = getBitmapFromPath();
        // Getting the bitmap in right orientation.
        this.mBitmap = rotateBitmap(rawBitmap, imageOrientationCode);
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmapFromPath() {
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(this.filePath, bmOptions);
        return bitmap;
    }

    private int getImageOrientation() {
        ExifInterface exif = null;
        try {
            exif = new ExifInterface(this.filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        assert exif != null;
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        return orientation;
    }

    private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int orientation){

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL:
                return bitmap;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_HORIZONTAL:
                matrix.setScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_FLIP_VERTICAL:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSPOSE:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_TRANSVERSE:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                matrix.postScale(-1, 1);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.setRotate(-90);
                break;
            default:
                return bitmap;
        }
        try {
            Bitmap bmRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
            bitmap.recycle();
            return bmRotated;
        }
        catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private String scanImage(){
        TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
        Log.d(Config.TAG, "Data path : " + FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPath));
        baseApi.init(FileUtils.getDirectory(this.directoryPath) + "/", this.trainedDataCode);
        baseApi.setImage(this.mBitmap);
        String recognizedText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
        baseApi.end();

        return recognizedText;
    }

    private void makeTessdataReady(){

        // created test data directory if necessary under absoluteDirectoryPath and returns its absolute path.
        String tessdirectoryPath = FileUtils.getTessdataDirectory(this.absoluteDirectoryPath);

        if (!(new File(tessdirectoryPath+ "/" + this.trainedDataCode + ".traineddata")).exists()) {
            try {

                AssetManager assetManager = mActivity.getAssets();
                InputStream in = assetManager.open("tessdata/" + this.trainedDataCode + ".traineddata");
                //GZIPInputStream gin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
                // Output stream with the location where we have to write the eng.traineddata file.
                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tessdirectoryPath + "/"  + this.trainedDataCode
                        + ".traineddata");

                // Transfer bytes from in to out
                byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                //while ((lenf = gin.read(buff)) > 0) {
                while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                    out.write(buf, 0, len);
                }
                in.close();
                //gin.close();
                out.close();

                Log.v(Config.TAG, "Copied " + " traineddata");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(Config.TAG, "Was unable to copy " + " traineddata " + e.toString());
            }
        }
        else{
            Log.d(Config.TAG, "tessdata already present");
        }
    }

}
```

I hope you guys can help me. It's been days to figure out what's wrong with this code.......

Comment: did you have successfully run the tesseract lib in android studio ?

Comment: @SagarNayak what do you mean by run tesseract lib? I can run my app there and I have included `compile project(':tess-two')` & `compile project(':easy_ocr_library')` in my project's gradle. Plus, the example app there works & I did follow all the guidance from the resources on the web.

Comment: yes . i am asking for the same. so you used ndk to build the tess-two ?

Comment: @SagarNayak yup I did use ndk build... If you want the full system code, I can give you in my GitHub to try...

Comment: sure. i would love to get it. i am trying the ocr for 15 days . and get stuck in the ndk build always.

Comment: @SagarNayak good for you, I was stuck on it for a month... Here: https://github.com/Kaydarin/Queue-App

Comment: thank you. will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that the camera activity does not return RESULT_OK, but RESULT_CANCELED - therefore tesseract is never called. You can verify this e. g. by adding in "Tab2.java" at the start of method "onActivityResult":

```
Log.d("PictureEdit", "onActivityResult w/ resultCode=" + resultCode + " (is ok: " + (resultCode == RESULT_OK) + " is canceled: " + (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) + ")" + " requestCode=" + requestCode);
```

Why is that so? Because starting with Android 6 (Marshmallow) it is not suffice to just declare the necessary permissions in the manifest. Additionally the permissions must got at runtime from the user.

See here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Here is the code I use for getting permissions to camera and r/w to external storage:

```
private void checkPermissions(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        boolean needWriteExtStorage = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        boolean needCamera = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (needWriteExtStorage || needCamera){
            String[] permissions = new String[((needWriteExtStorage)?(1):(0)) + ((needCamera)?(1):(0))];
            int idx = 0;
            if (needWriteExtStorage){
                permissions[idx] = android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
                idx++;
            }
            if (needCamera){
                permissions[idx] = android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA;
                idx++;
            }
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, permissions, 1);
        }
    } else { 
        //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
        //Log.e("testing", "Permission is already granted");
    }
}
```